# Startup Script in rc2.d - Delayed Execution

Tags: bash, scripts, autorun

I have a script which I'm wanting to run at start-up.

It's a very simple script which inserts a few kernel modules and starts `vino-server`:

## init-script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo rmmod nvhost_vi

# Insert the camera modules
sudo modprobe videobuf2-dma-contig
sudo modprobe adv7280
sudo modprobe tegra_camera

# Start the VNC server
cd /usr/lib/vino
./vino-server &
```

And I've added a symlink into the `/etc/rc2.d` directory, I've ensure that execute permissions have been applied to this script.

If I reboot the system, I notice (checking out `dmesg`) that the script isn't run until approximately 260 seconds after boot - not during the boot sequence as expected.

Is there any reason why this would be happening? This version of Ubuntu (14.04.5 LTS) is running on an NVIDIA Jetson TK1 board which is an ARM core.

To throw a fly in the ointment, I have an *identical* set-up (from the same deployment image) which DOES NOT exhibit this behaviour. The same script in the same rc2.d directory DOES run at startup (13 seconds after boot).

Answer (score 1):

Your post doesn't explains how the link is named inside the `/etc/rc2.d` folder. If you want to register a custom startup script you should place it inside the `/etc/init.d` directory and register it with [update-rc.d](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-rc.d.8.html).

```
$ sudo cp /home/user/mod_and_vnc /etc/init.d/
$ sudo update-rc.d mod_and_vnc defaults

$ ls -la /etc/rc*.d/*mod_and_vnc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jul 19 15:11 /etc/rc0.d/K20mod_and_vnc -> ../init.d/mod_and_vnc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jul 19 15:11 /etc/rc1.d/K20mod_and_vnc -> ../init.d/mod_and_vnc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jul 19 15:11 /etc/rc2.d/S20mod_and_vnc -> ../init.d/mod_and_vnc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jul 19 15:11 /etc/rc3.d/S20mod_and_vnc -> ../init.d/mod_and_vnc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jul 19 15:11 /etc/rc4.d/S20mod_and_vnc -> ../init.d/mod_and_vnc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jul 19 15:11 /etc/rc5.d/S20mod_and_vnc -> ../init.d/mod_and_vnc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jul 19 15:11 /etc/rc6.d/K20mod_and_vnc -> ../init.d/mod_and_vnc
```